# Concatenate folder name into file

Tags: bash, terminal

If I have a bunch of folders (f1, f2, f3) and they all have images in them (image1.jpg, image2.jpg) - I'd like to add the folder name into the image name itself.

Ie: f1_image1.jpg

What's the best way to do this? Preferably something I can run on Terminal.

Comment: use a for loop and the mv command..?

Comment: Is there a script for this?

Comment: You could write a script easily enough.  GIve it a shot, and we'll help you fix it. Experimentation is the best way to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
for dir in * 
do
    for image in ${dir}/*.jpg
    do
        image_name=$(echo ${image} | cut -f2 -d/)
        mv "${image}" "${dir}_${image_name}"
    done
done
```

Comment: Maybe it worked for you, but it's broken: will break if filename contains multiple successive blanks, or newlines, or glob characters…

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
for dir in *
do
    for image in ${dir}/*.jpg
    do
        # remove the 'echo' if you think this works for you
        echo mv "${image}" "${dir}_$(basename ${image})"
    done
done
```

Comment: It's getting the folder_folder/image when I want it as folder_image.jpg

Comment: @user1883614: Ah... right. My bad. Answer corrected.

Comment: A few improvements: `for dir in */`to be sure we loop on directories; `for image in "$dir"*.jpg` (quote expansion of `$dir`); `mv -- "$image" "${dir%/}_${image##*/}"` (use parameter expansion instead of a subshell and external program, for efficiency and because `basename` is useless here). Also, would be more robust with `shopt -s nullglob`.

Comment: I find `$(basename ${image})` more expressive than `${image##*/}`. The rest are valid issues *if you want to create a production-quality, reusable script*. For one-shot solutions, I usually don't bother. +1 for mentioning them, though.

Answer (score 0):

Some one liner based on find

```
find <path> -type f -exec  sh -c 'mv {} $(dirname {})/$(basename $(dirname {}))_$(basename {})' \;
```

where `<path>` is the root folder of your bunch of folders

example:

create the example files

```
mkdir -p /tmp/ffff/f{1,2,3} 
touch /tmp/ffff/f{1,2,3}/image{1,2,3,4}.jpg
```

run

```
find /tmp/ffff -type f
```

you will get

```
/tmp/ffff/f3/image4.jpg
/tmp/ffff/f3/image3.jpg
/tmp/ffff/f3/image2.jpg
/tmp/ffff/f3/image1.jpg
/tmp/ffff/f2/image4.jpg
/tmp/ffff/f2/image3.jpg
/tmp/ffff/f2/image2.jpg
/tmp/ffff/f2/image1.jpg
/tmp/ffff/f1/image4.jpg
/tmp/ffff/f1/image3.jpg
/tmp/ffff/f1/image2.jpg
/tmp/ffff/f1/image1.jpg
```

run

```
find /tmp/ffff -type f -exec  sh -c 'mv {} $(dirname {})/$(basename $(dirname {}))_$(basename {})' \;
```

run again

```
find /tmp/ffff -type f
```

you will get

```
/tmp/ffff/f3/f3_image1.jpg
/tmp/ffff/f3/f3_image2.jpg
/tmp/ffff/f3/f3_image3.jpg
/tmp/ffff/f3/f3_image4.jpg
/tmp/ffff/f2/f2_image1.jpg
/tmp/ffff/f2/f2_image2.jpg
/tmp/ffff/f2/f2_image3.jpg
/tmp/ffff/f2/f2_image4.jpg
/tmp/ffff/f1/f1_image1.jpg
/tmp/ffff/f1/f1_image2.jpg
/tmp/ffff/f1/f1_image3.jpg
/tmp/ffff/f1/f1_image4.jpg
```